# JQuery Mobile search filter

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to figure out how to increase the size of the search filter bar for jquery mobile. Right now I have a content div with the following ul tag:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="alistview" data-inset="false" data-filter="true"></ul>
```

My full working header is:

```
<div data-role="page" id="aPage" data-hash="false">
    <div data-role="content">   
            <h3>Header</h3>     
        <ul data-role="listview" id="alistview" data-inset="false" data-filter="true"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my css I have tried both:

```
.ui-listview-filter{
    height: 10%;
    font-size 120%;
}
```

and:

```
#alistview .ui-listview-filter{
    height: 10%;
    font-size 120%;
}
```

but neither of them worked. I'm pretty sure I'm using the correct class for styling. When I did a ctrl-shift-j in Chrome on the code it shows a segment of code for the search bar that is not in my source code which I assume is generated by setting `data-filter ="true"` Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is using `height:` with a percentage. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height):

> The  is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   containing block. If the height of the containing block is not
>   specified explicitly, the value computes to auto. A percentage height
>   on the root element (e.g. ) is relative to the initial
>   containing block (whose dimensions are equal to the dimensions of the
>   viewport).

Therefore, it's best to either **a)** set the height of the parent `<div data-role="content">`, or **b)** set the height to a pixel amount.

Use your original code to edit the spacing of the area around the input:

```
.ui-listview-filter {
    height: 100px;
}
```

[**jsfiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/XGvhE/1/)

and modifying Thanassis_K's `input` code from above, it's best not to use percentage font-sizes on elements other than the body tag. Use `px` or `em` instead:

```
.ui-listview-filter input {
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

[**jsfiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/XGvhE/2/)

Comment: But he could at least be able to notice the affect to the font size regardless of the height, right?

Comment: I want to use % to deal with different device screen sizes, but I guess this will work for now. Thank you

Comment: @rsayles3, like I mentioned, you could likely specify the height for the parent container and you'll then be able to set this element to a percentage height. May take some tinkering but that's the idea

Comment: @rsayles3 Just curious. When you had the height as a percentage, you did not notice the change at the font size? When you changed the height to be fixed pixels, you then noticed the change at font size?

Comment: @Thanassis_K that is correct, I did not notice a change when I had the height as a percentage

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a : in your code next to font-size. Try

```
.ui-listview-filter{
    height: 10%;
    font-size: 120%;
}
```

and see if that helps

Comment: if this fixes his problem - he's going to facepalm.

Comment: Fortunately for my face this did not fix the problem ;)

Comment: Glad your face is OK ;)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to increase the height and the font size of the `<input>` inside the filter bar, correct?

Then you could do something like:

```
.ui-listview-filter input{
    height: 10%;
    font-size 120%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kakarikos/XGvhE/)

Comment: I want to increase the size of the filter bar itself. adding `input` did not correct my problem

Comment: Could you please check that [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kakarikos/XGvhE/) and see if it helps?

Comment: It works in your jsfiddle but it doesn't work in my code. I don't understand why

Comment: I could help you further if you could post a working sample of your code.

Comment: Check if Jquery mobile version on fiddle same as yours?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the entire working div. Also, the jquery mobile versions are the same

Comment: That is not make any difference... Do you have the css rule in a separate css file? Could you make sure you cleared the browser's cache?